# How to close/disconnect Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: disconnect, citrix

I'm currently killing (signal 9) the Citrix process after finished using it.  Is there a better way to gracefully disconnect the Citrix connection?

Note: I don't see any Citrix panel and I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch to host and switch to remote machine and hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

When in VPN, press Ctrl + F2 to switch out of VPN.  Locate Citrix in the taskbar, right click, select quit and confirm.